# How to iterate in a union type array in angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am new to angular and started working on version 12 and I am stuck in a point. Where
I want to iterate in my union array in the template but it gives me error.

Error:
Type 'IBasketItem[] | IOrderItem[]' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable'.

this is my union array in the component on which I want to iterate.

```
@Input() items: IBasketItem[] | IOrderItem[] = [];
```

this is the template code

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items" class="border-0">
```

it gives me a red line under the ' of ' keyword with above mentioned error

here is the IBasketItem interface

```
export interface IBasketItem {
id: number;
productName: string;
price: number;
quantity: number;
pictureUrl: string;
brand: string;
type: string;
```

}

and this is the IOrderItem interface

```
export interface IOrderItem {
productId: number;
productName: string;
pictureUrl: string;
price: number;
quantity: number;
```

}

I will be thankful if someone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Declare array of type like this

<s>`@Input() items: [IBasketItem | IOrderItem] = [];`</s>

This is iterable then.

OR this way

`@Input() items:  Array<IBasketItem | IOrderItem> = [];`

Comment: thank for your time but your solution are not working for me. when I applied your solutions it unable to find properties in my interfaces.

Comment: @Fahad look at my answer. In special remark 1

Answer (score 1):

while @Hitech answer might work, what you are trying to do is a bit sketchy.
You will have to check if you have the 'brand' or 'type' property available and then display them or have different logic for an orderItem or for a basketItem.

I recommend you have a common interface for both of them and then iterate through that array:

```
export interface IItem {
    id: number;
    productName: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
    pictureUrl: string;
}

export interface IOrderItem extends IItem {
    productId: number; // might be the same with the id from the base class, depending on your logic
}

export interface IBasketItem extends IItem {
    brand: string;
    type: string;
}

@Input() items: IItem[] = [];
```

or have two separate arrays for this and have a for loop for each of them.

```
@Input() basketItems: IBasketItem [] = [];
@Input() odredItems: IOrderItem [] = [];
```

Comment: @qbBlaze thanks for your such effort but sadly your 1st solution is not working for me and for 2nd solution, I cannot use separate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting error. My intern got the same error and understanding the error message, I see the problem.

```
@Input() items: IBasketItem[] | IOrderItem[] = [];
```

When you declare a union that the types can be 2 different arrays you don't have an array iterator for both arrays, in fact, you have one for each possible array. That's why the compiler throws an error, it doesn´t know which iterator to use.

```
@Input() items: (IBasketItem | IOrderItem)[] = [];
```

So, to solve the problem you need to assure that you have just one iterator, a list of union type. This solution solves our same problem.

Few remarks about this solution:

1. As you are handling a union type, you only can access directly properties that have an intersection in the Union, or you should use a type guard and handle each union type.
2. `(IBasketItem | IOrderItem)[]` allows you to have an array with mixed types, and if you do that, the compiler won´t throw an error. But in general, you are always receiving as input one type array. This shouldn't be a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular checks the expressions and bindings within the templates in the application code. Try setting `"strictTemplates": false` in `tsconfig.json` file and you should be fine.

Comment: Watchout setting it to false, because it is a really useful config